# Groovy MarkupBuilder node

Tags: xml, groovy

Consider the following code:

```
def builder = new MarkupBuilder()
builder.root() {
}
```

I would like to delegate creation of the children of root to a separate method. How can I accomplish this task? Some options to consider are creating and returning a node from a method or passing in the parent node and adding them in the method (both examples would be useful).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Groovy website](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+MarkupBuilder+for+Agile+XML+creation) contains an explanation on how to achieve this.

Sample:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.books() {
   createBookNode(xml, 2, 'mrhaki')
}

def createBookNode(builder, repeat, username) {
    repeat.times {
       builder.person(name: username)
    }
}

println writer.toString()
```

Output will be:

```
<books>
    <person name="mrhaki"/>
    <person name="mrhaki"/>
</books>
```